# cost function after converting tf.layers to tf.keras.layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a CNN where output dimension is [None, 10]

It is a multi-label problem, where output signifies possible categories which x might belong. (eg, an image can be classified as `cat` `dark` and so on)

Following is what I have now, how can I change the code to keras version? 
I can't find equivalent of `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`

```
 model = tf.layers.dense(L3, category_num, activation=None)
 cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model, labels=Y)

 cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, axis=1))
 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct alternative in Keras is to use sigmoid activation in your output layer and binary_crossentropy as cost function.

```
net.add(Dense(..., activation='sigmoid'))
net.compile(optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Take a look https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/741

Answer (score 0):

In Keras:

```
#you model here -- last layer:

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])
```